# Orthogonal component of Orthogonal component of a vector

Tags: vectors

My doubt is on orthogonal component of an orthogonal component of a vector.

In the image attached below, let $OA$ be a vector and $OM$ and $ON$ be its orthogonal component. ON makes an angle of $θ$ with OA.

So $OM = OA sin θ$

$ON = OA cos θ$

Now let $OP ⟂ OA$ be drawn. So orthogonal component of $OM$ is along $OA$ and $OP$
So along $OP$ the magnitude of the orthogonal component is $ON sin θ = OA cos θ sin θ$

But as $OP ⟂ OA$, so no component of $OA$ should exist along $OP$ but we found a component equal to $OA cos θ sin θ$. This seems like a contradiction. I am eagerly looking forward to grab the correct concept as, for the topic Vector, I only depended on myself and books and so I think I have a wrong conception.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are confused with the concept "orthogonal component". When you are considering orthogonal components you are usually interested in decomposing a vector into two orthogonal components, such that the sum reconstructs the original vector.

We start with the vector $\vec A$. We then want to decompose $\vec A$ into two components using the vector $\vec N$ such that one component is along $\vec N$. I will call this component the "parallel component". You can show that the vector $c\vec N$ where $c=(\vec N\cdot\vec A)/(\vec N\cdot \vec N)$ has length $A\cos\theta$ and also points in the direction of $\vec N$. So the parallel component is given by $$\vec A_\parallel=c\vec N.$$
Now we can define the orthogonal component as
$$\vec A_\perp=\vec A-\vec A_\parallel.$$
Using some more work you can show that $\vec A_\parallel\cdot\vec A_\perp=0$, which means they are orthogonal to each other. The sum reconstructs the original vector, $\vec A=\vec A_\parallel+\vec A_\perp$, so it is a proper decomposition.

When you introduce $\vec P$, you again perform a projection. This time $\vec P$ is already orthogonal to $\vec A$ so when we perform the decomposition something special happens. We get
\begin{align}
\vec A_\parallel&=0\\
\vec A_\perp&=\vec A
\end{align}
So, like you showed, there is no component of $\vec A$ along $\vec P$. The "orthogonal component" of $\vec P$ is just $\vec A_\perp$, which in this case has length $A$.